# CKEditor5 markdown and superscript not working?

Tags: ckeditor, markdown, ckeditor5, superscript

I am using CKEditor 5, Inline Editor with [Markdown](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_markdown-gfm_markdown-Markdown.html) and [Superscript](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_basic-styles_superscript-Superscript.html) plugins. As per the [git](https://gist.github.com/wildmichael/5064046) documentation superscript is represented as `<sup></sup>` in markdown. Setting the data via editor works perfectly.
Example: `editor.setData("* **Per** modified decision <sup>tree</sup>.")`
However, `editor.getData()` returns the markdown without the sup tags. `* **Per** modified decision tree.`
How can I configure the editor to allow  tags in the markdown data returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would retain the 'sup' or any other html tags in the markdown output.
`editor.data.processor.keepHtml('sup')`